# How to refresh spring integration poller with @RefreshScope?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Cloud Config to refresh its properties. I can easily refresh my controllers with `@RefreshScope` but I'm not sure how I can do the same for my `poller` to restart my Spring Integration job.

My integration-config.xml :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/workspace/config/tasky-dev.properties" />

<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="tasksService" method="requestAllTasks" channel="initTimestampChannel">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="${start.task.rate}"></int:poller>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

If I change `start.task.rate`, then hit `/refresh`, the actuator detects the change but nothing is picked up by my `poller`. Is there any way to define some sort of `@RefreshScope` for it ?

My `tasky-dev.properties` :

```
start.task.rate=600000
```

My Application.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
@ImportResource("classpath:integration-config.xml")
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

=======

Update :

Attempting Artem's solution with setting a `PeriodicTrigger`. The scope is refreshed but only when the poller is recalled (once the fixedRate duration has passed):

```
@RefreshScope
@Bean
public PeriodicTrigger refreshablePeriodicTrigger() {
    PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger = new PeriodicTrigger(fixedRate);
    periodicTrigger.setFixedRate(true);
    return periodicTrigger;
}
```

And :

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="tasksService" method="requestAllTasks" channel="initTimestampChannel">
    <int:poller trigger="refreshablePeriodicTrigger"></int:poller>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that convenient `<poller>` registers essentially a `Trigger` object to be used by the `TaskScheduler.schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger)`.

What I can suggest you is to register a `PeriodicTrigger` bean in some `@Configuration` with `@RefreshScope` and use it in the `<poller>` definition instead of `fixed-rate` property.

Comment: I've updated my post. It's almost what I'm trying to do. With your solution the scope is refreshed but only when the poller is recalled (once the fixedRate duration has passed), how can I reinitialize the `refreshablePeriodicTrigger` immediately when the `fixedRate` is  refreshed ?

Comment: Well, you can `stop()` an `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` during refresh, but the task in progress is going to finish anyway.

Comment: Thank you Artem for all your answers. I finally realized that all I've been doing is counterproductive, I have at least 20 other elements using properties in my XML, I need to do the same to each and everyone of them. It would be so much more easier and cleaner to just switch to a Java DSL configuration if I want to be able to refresh my beans. I thought there'd be some Spring Integration magic pill that will allow all my beans to be refreshable directly from my XML.

Comment: Yeah... unfortunately that’s not. An XML is parsed to a set of beans and at runtime we have a model slightly different than it is with XML DSL. Also RefreshScope has been introduced far later after XML configuration and looks like it is designed for Java config anyway